# How to Ignore Shadow Properties using EF Database-First approach to Scaffold-DBContext and Generate Separate Trackable class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using the Entity Framework Database-First approach previously I have used the Code-First approach and created a Tracking class for common properties and inherit all the entities from it as shown below:

```
public abstract class Trackable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedUser { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedUser { get; set; }
}

public class User: Trackable
{
    [Key]
    public new int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

above code generated single table having all the properties exist in User as well as Trackable class.
Now I need to generate the same output(I mean classes) while using Database-First approach.

I have tried but it generated a single **User** class having all the properties that exist in the table inside the Database.

**Can anyone guide me that what should I need to do to achieve the expected result same as in the case of Code-First I have done?**

Comment: A combination of excluded columns and HandleBars templates with EF Core Power Tools might work, but this is not what "database first" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @Muhammad Shahid Khan Afridi，

> above code generated single table having all the properties exist in
> User as well as Trackable class.

According to your class, I have add the following code in the DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<User> AppUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Then, after migration using EF code first, it will create a Users table in the database, like this:

[image]

> Can anyone guide me that what should I need to do to achieve the
> expected result same as in the case of Code-First I have done?

Now, it seems that you want to generate the related class (with inheritance) using EF Database-first, I assume you are using the ADO.Net Entity Data Model, if that is the case, after generate the related class, as you said, we can only get a single User class in the .edmx file, like this:

[image]

Here you can refer the following steps to change the tables:

First, right click the **User** entity, and open the **Properties** panel, change the "Entity Set Name" and "Name" property.(change the name from "Users" to "DBF_Users", this is used to prevent the `Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'User'` error).

[image]

After that save the changes (click the OK button):

[image]

Then, change the user class as below (remember to add the Table attribute to map the table in the database) and save changes:

[image]

After that you could refer the following code to use the genrested class:

[image]

Comment: because this change is in the auto generated .cs file - does that mean each time the User Table is updated he will have to edit that .cs file again?

Comment: Hi @DawoodAwan, Yes, we have to manually update the classes. Because, Database First will auto generated one table with all of the properties, instead of using inheritance.

Comment: so wouldn't it better to do those changes in a partial class in a separate file? so every time the class changes we won't need to modify the EF generated file.

Comment: Hi @DawoodAwan, The Database First is designed to automatically generate the class based on the existing database, so, it will generate all the properties to one class based on the table structure. From your description, it seems that you will modify the class (properties or inheritance) frequently, if that is the case, EF Code-First might be more suitable for you.

Comment: Yes according to your answer, that's why i suggested you should of added a separate file with a partial class to make your changes - instead of making changes to the file generate by EF